# How to define and pass arguments to docker file when we want to run a java app using CMD command?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a docker file and I want to use it to run a spring boot application. Here is my docker file :

```
// some other command...

FROM ${REGISTRY}eclipse-temurin:17-jre-alpine
ARG JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED"
COPY --from=builder /opt/my-app.jar /opt/my-app.jar
CMD ["java", "${JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS}","-jar","/opt/my-app.jar"]
```

The problem is that when I start the docker container I get this error messasge :

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ${JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS}
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ${JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS}
```

I don't know how to fix this problem.

P.s: `${JAVA_OPTS}` in `ARG JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS` comes from a docker compose file.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Docker compose is not the same as dockerfile, I think it's ENV your after, the documentation for dockerfile should explain this

Comment: The exec form `CMD ["java", ...]` doesn't expand environment variables.  The easiest change is to remove the JSON array and make it a simple string `CMD java ${JAVA_JDK_OPTIONS} ...`; Docker will process this with a shell, which will expand the environment variable.  Also note that you'll need to change the `ARG` to `ENV` to have it visible in the final image.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this command for passing the arguments

```
> docker run -it your-java-app-image java -jar your-java-app.jar arg1 arg2
```